Which glazing liquid should I choose, gloss or satin?
I have never used glazing liquids before. I recently got the chance to try out Golden Glazing liquid for acrylic which comes in Gloss and Satin version. But I can only try out one. The effects that I'm looking for are:

Should increase the vibrancy (like a sunset).
Should increase the richness of dark paints (darken the darks).
Should not shine like a glass or mirror.

I understand Satin version should have a reduced gloss effect but does it also increase the richness and vibrancy like the gloss counterpart? Also how shiny the gloss version is?

I'm not sure this is really answerable, since you're asking after a specific product (that I'm not familiar with), that may differ from other products.
Nevertheless, generally speaking, applying glazes over existing paint layers can enrich the underlying colour, but can also dull it down, since you're basically mixing colours.
For example, for a bright sunset, you might want to initially paint the bright light areas white, then, after it has sufficiently dried, add a slightly coloured yellow or red glaze on top, to give it a little hue.
However, if you were to glaze a red over an existing green layer, the result would be a darker greyer colour.
As for the glossiness: satin will indeed have duller reflections, and gloss will dry up to reflect a lot of light. How much exactly, however, I can not tell, because these terms only have a relative meaning (AFAIK), but I can imagine gloss is usually made to reflect as much light as possible within the constraints of the product.
Often, there is a third option, matte, which would be the dullest version, but Golden doesn't appear to have that version.
Gloss varnishes tend to saturate colours more than satin, so I assume it will work similarly for this glaze: for richer colours, pick gloss. But, again, this depends a lot on what colours you're glazing with and over.
You can, of course, always opt to varnish your entire piece afterwards to get an even sheen.

Understood. Yes, I did not consider the effect of certain colours over their complimentary ones. That makes sense.
